# Regex - Check if string contains partial URL and convert to link

Tags: javascript, regex

I just can't get my head around regex and this is driving me crazy.

I have the following string;

```
'This is a random string of text with a link to google.com/test and another link to facebook.com`
```

What I want to do, is turn `google.com/test` into `https://google.com/test` but leave the `facebook.com` link as plain text.

So basically, any instance of `google.com` (Including with prefixes) would turn into a link, but any other URL would remain as plain text.

Can someone give me a nudge in the right direction please?

Answer (score 2):

Simple `replace()` will do:

```js
var str = 'This is a random string of text with a link to google.com/test and another link to facebook.com';
str = str.replace('google.com/test', 'https://google.com/test');
console.log(str);
```